# Turn off language localization on VLC player in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, vlc, language-support

I'm using Kubuntu 18.10, and VLC (3.0.4) which was installed by default.

The problem I have is that I cannot change the language of the interface to English. When I searched for "how to change the language of VLC" I found screenshots of preferences window where there is drop down option to select the language.

However here is my a screenshot of preferences, in this awful mixture of grammatically incorrect Croatian and English, and the option to select the language is missing:

[image]

Please help, the software is completely unusable like this.

Comment: Probably you have the VLC snap then. Can you please confirm by letting us know the output of the terminal command: `which vlc`

Comment: `which vlc` outputs `/usr/bin/vlc`. It's the one that came with Kubuntu installation.

Comment: Ok, then you have the .deb package VLC. You already have two answers below. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there is a language selector in VLC for Linux. It must have been a screenshot from Windows. You can still change the locale of a program, by launching it like so: `LANGUAGE=en programname`.

For example, `LANGUAGE=en vlc`.

In case you want to make it permanent, edit vlc launcher `/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop`, and add `env LANGUAGE=en` to the `Exec ...` line to make it look like this:

`Exec=env LANGUAGE=en /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U`

Comment: +1. It works for me. Also the shorter `LANG=C vlc` works for me.

Comment: It should be noted that changes to the `.desktop` file are overwritten at next upgrade of the VLC package. In my answer I point at a more sustainable method which survives package upgrades.

Comment: Making a copy of *vlc.desktop* in `~/.local/share/applications` and editing that file would also survive package upgrades.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Ubuntu 23.10, vlc 3.0.18

Answer (score 5):

This is one way to make VLC start in English:

- Create the file `~/bin/vlc`
- Give it this contents:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  export LANGUAGE=en
  exec /usr/bin/vlc $@
  ```
- Make it executable:

  ```
  chmod +x ~/bin/vlc
  ```

Possibly you need to relogin before it starts working.